# document.ready() just running one function instead of two

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, document-ready

I'm trying to run two js functions(i'm using jquery) in the document.ready(), but only runs one. Here is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    show_properties();
    table_events();
 });
```

the functions are written in the same js file, but only show_properties() is loaded when the website loads.  I tested in the firebug console to write

> table_events()

and the console tells me "undefined", but after that the function gets loaded and the ajax calls and everything inside that function starts to work.

Why is that?  How can I fix this behavior?

thanks.

Here are the functions I want to run:

```
    function table_events(){
 $.ajaxSetup ({  
         cache: false  
     });  

 var wait = "<img src='../images/loading_red_transparent.gif' alt='loading...' style='display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;'/>";    

    $('.apartamentos tr').on('click', function() {
            alert("hola.")
               var id_propiedad = $(this).find(".id_propiedad").html();   
           var nombre_propiedad = $(this).find(".nombre_propiedad").html(); 
       //$('#property_information').hide('slow');

       $("#property_information")
       .html(wait)
       .load('properties_info.php',{'nombre_propiedad':nombre_propiedad,'id_propiedad':id_propiedad});
       //$('#property_information').show('slow');

        }); 


 }


 function show_properties(){
 $.ajaxSetup ({  
         cache: false  
     }); 
 var wait = "<img src='../images/loading_red_transparent.gif' alt='loading...' style='display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;'/>";

     $('#busca_propiedades').on('click',function(){

         var user_id = $('#user_list').val();

         /*var data = $.ajax({
              url: "properties_list.php",
              type: 'POST',
              data:{ 'user_id': user_id },
              cache: false,
              async: false
             }).responseText;

         });*/

         $('#lista_aptos')
         .html(wait)
         .load('properties_list.php',{'user_id':user_id});

        //alert(data);
         });

 }
```

EDIT:
after some debugging with console.log , i found out that this code is the one that's not executing when the webpage loads:

```
$('.apartamentos tr').on('click', function() {
            alert("hola.")
               var id_propiedad = $(this).find(".id_propiedad").html();   
           var nombre_propiedad = $(this).find(".nombre_propiedad").html(); 
       //$('#property_information').hide('slow');

       $("#property_information")
       .html(wait)
       .load('properties_info.php',{'nombre_propiedad':nombre_propiedad,'id_propiedad':id_propiedad});
       //$('#property_information').show('slow');

        });
```

apparently, this function() is the one that doesn't run when the webpage loads; but when I write again in the console

> table_events()

THEN the code inside this function runs when I click in the tr of the table.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have any errors in `show_properties`'?

Comment: what happens if you reverse the order? How do you know table_events didn't run?

Comment: Does your table_events(); function actually exist outside of the $(document).ready?

Comment: Any javascript errors? Include more content(code) as something seems broken or just wrong.

Comment: Is there anything in `show_properties` which `table_events` is dependant on? Such as AJAX requests?

Comment: If you say the function is loaded at a later time the problem may be due to positioning / ordering of the code?

Comment: where is `table_events` defined?

Comment: Seems like you're executing `table_events` before some other asynchronous code finishes loading.

Comment: Hi all.  Even if I reverse the order only show_properties() gets loaded when the website loads

Comment: and I don't get javascript errors in the console; only when I write "table_events()" in the console to run it, it prints "undefined", but then the code works

Answer (score 1):

Are `$('.apartamentos tr')` elements loaded with the `load` call in `show_properties`?

If yes then the problem is due to the fact that when `table_events` is executed, tr elements are not yet inserted in the `#lista_aptos` (cause `load` uses ajax, that's asynchronous).

To check please add

```
console.log("trs count: ", $('.apartamentos tr').size());
```

on top of your table_events function.

To fix you should pass `table_events` as completetion handler to `load` call:

```
$('#lista_aptos')
         .html(wait)
         .load('properties_list.php',{'user_id':user_id}, table_events);
```

---

### Old response

You said "...after that the function gets loaded and the ajax calls..."

Keep in mind that ajax calls are asynchronous.

If you define the table_events function inside the ajax response handler, also if you do something to put it in a scope visible from the referencing function, the attempt to call table_events may occur before the table_events definition.

or, as Raghavan says, there's an error thrown from show_properties that prevents the execution of table_events. But better if you try to debug with console.log("text") instead of alert (alert is blocking and it will hide you problems from asynchronous calls)

please, try to make a example on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: This is worth investigating, the function could be called as part of the "success" event, if jQuery's AJAX function is being used.

Comment: I added some console.log events inside table_events(), and eventhough the console log msgs are printed, the console.log that is inside the function() of the click event doesn't load when the web pages loads.

Answer (score 0):

If the console returns "undefined" that means the function exists, but it's returning undefined as a result.

Your function needs fixing, $(document).ready() is probably fine.

Try calling `table_events()` at the last line in `show_properties()` and see if that works.

Comment: I tried running it at the end of show_properties(), and still didn't run the function

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

Does table_events exist in the scope of $(document).ready?

Is show_properties possibly raising an error?

This may be a good case for "alert debugging":

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    show_properties();
    // You might also put an alert at the very end of show_properties.
    alert('show_properties called; now calling table_events()');
    table_events();
    alert('table_events called; document.ready done');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an error in the table_events function. Try debugging using simple alert statements.